# how to concatenate two variable values with different rows in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I have two variable or files with strings like

```
a="p|q"

b="x y z"
```

b variable has three characters separate by space.

my question is how to generate output as using a shell command in Linux with separator as "|"

```
p|q|x
p|q|y
p|q|z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if I understand your question correctly. The following `for`-loop will give you the output you want:
`for i in $b; do echo "$a|$i"; done`

Comment: that's correct, is there any other way then using a loop?

Comment: you could use `sed` like this: `echo $b | sed "s/^/$a|/" | sed "s/\s/\n$a|/g"`, although I would prefer the `for` loop, as that command is easier to read/understand

Comment: Instead of single-quoting the `'|'` in your concatenated string (which does nothing), why not double quote the whole string `"$a|$b"`?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it without a loop, but it's not recommended in general:

```
printf "$a|%s\n" $b
```

- `$a` is expanded before the command is run, so your format string ends up as `'p|q|%s\n'`
- `$b` is also expanded and since it is unquoted, each word becomes a separate argument

So the command you run is:

```
printf 'p|q|%s\n' x y z
```

which produces the output you wanted.

Note that this is not ideal because:

1. In general, putting variables into a `printf` format string can lead to unexpected output (e.g. if the variable contains characters like %s).
2. Deliberately using unquoted variables reads like a typo to a lot of people, so you probably need to add a comment to explain that you're being clever.